# Is this Bug in wso2dss

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

> ```
>      How we can avoid the @nil=true in WSO2DSS
>
>         we are using POSTGRESSQL database. my tables has NULL data 
>         while i am retrieving from data base using wso2dss and wso2esb i am getting it as object Json
>         which define like this {"@nil":"true"}
>         how we can get NULL in wso2dss.i need to set any properties in wso2dss
>         for clarification please refer this 
>
>         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020186/how-we-can-override-a-wso2-dss-nil-true-value`
>         i stuck in middle my application not running because of this object i need to replace it with "NULL"
> ```
>
> i am getting like this

{"Body":{"Datalist":{"username":{"@nil":"true"},"password":{"@nil":"true"}}}}

```
   But i need in this format






          {"Body":{"Datalist":{"username":"NULL","password":"NULL"}}}
        Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug but the standard representation of "NULL" in XML. For more details, please refer my answer upon the stackoverflow query at [1]

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194678/959669

Cheers,
Prabath